# Is there a way in R i can create a new polygon (representing a certain constant value) based on two polygons representing 2 different constant values

Tags: r, polygon, spatial-interpolation

1. I have two polygons, an outer polygon and an inner polygon
2. The inner polygon is a polygon `pol1` (red) for a  parameter
   with a `value = 10`
3. The outer polygon is a polygon `pol2` (blue) for a parameter
   with a `value = 20`
4. I need to draw a polygon for a `value = 13` that would lie somewhere
   between `pol1` and `pol2`
5. This is almost like buffering but not quite since buffering would
   only give me a constant distance.This is some sort of interpolation.
6. I think the solution would be like calculating distances from the odes in the inner polygon `pol1` to the nearest edge of `pol2`
7. Then interpolating the distance for `value = 13` for each node.
8. Then calculate the new points for a polygon `pol3` for `value= 13`.
9. I could tediously try to code this but i imagine there may be a
   quicker/simpler solution Is there any tool that can help me to solve
   this. I would like Something that can be used with sf objects in R.

The code below is just for producing `pol1` and `pol2` which I hope someone can use to create a solution.

(In reality i have a more complex sf objects read from .shp files so I am thankful if you have example with such files )

[image: sketech of the desired result]

```
 library(sf)


    #polygon1 value=10
    lon = c(21, 22,23,24,22,21)
    lat = c(1,2,1,2,3,1)
    Poly_Coord_df = data.frame(lon, lat)
    pol1 = st_polygon(
        list(
            cbind(
                Poly_Coord_df$lon,
                Poly_Coord_df$lat)
        )
    )
    
    
    
    #polygon2 value =20
    lon = c(21, 20,22,25,22,21)
    lat = c(0,3,5,4,-3,0)
    Poly_Coord_df = data.frame(lon, lat)
    pol2 = st_polygon(
        list(
            cbind(
                Poly_Coord_df$lon,
                Poly_Coord_df$lat)
        )
    )
    
    
    plot(pol2,border="blue")
    plot(pol1,border="red",add=T)

# How to create pol3 with value = 13?
```

Comment: It looks like you'll want to interpolate some [contour lines](https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/interpolation-in-r.html), adding 20 to your first Poly_coord_df$elev <- 20, and 10 to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to go through inverse distance weighted interpolation and "contour" the resulting raster. For *idw* to work, we first need a set of locations and a grid that defines resulting locations. For input locations we'll first segementize polygon lines so we would have bit more than just corner locations, then cast to `POINT`s. For the grid we'll first build a polygon that covers interpolation area and input polygon lines; this will be turned into `stars` raster. This also defines `idw()` output objects, which we can pass to `stars::st_contour()` to get polygons or linestings.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
library(gstat)
library(ggplot2)

# inner polygon, value = 10
pol1 <- structure(list(structure(c(21, 22, 23, 24, 22, 21, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1), 
                                 dim = c(6L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))
# outer polygon, value = 20
pol2 <- structure(list(structure(c(21, 20, 22, 25, 22, 21, 0, 3, 5, 4, -3, 0), 
                                 dim = c(6L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))

# sf object with value attributes
poly_sf <- st_sf(geometry = st_sfc(pol1, pol2), value = c(10, 20))

# mask for interpolation zone, polygon with hole, buffered
mask_sf <- st_difference(pol2, pol1) |> st_buffer(.1)

# points along LINESTRING, first segmentize so we would not end up with just 
# corner points
points_sf <- poly_sf |>
  st_segmentize(.1) |>
  st_cast("POINT")
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(st_segmentize(poly_sf, 0.1), "POINT"): repeating
#> attributes for all sub-geometries for which they may not be constant

# stars raster that defines interpolated output raster
grd <- st_bbox(mask_sf) |>
  st_as_stars(dx = .05) |>
  st_crop(mask_sf)


p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_stars(data = grd, aes(fill = as.factor(values))) +
  geom_sf(data = poly_sf, aes(color = as.factor(value)), fill = NA, linewidth = 1, alpha = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = points_sf, shape = 1, size = 2) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(na.value = "transparent", name = "grd raster", alpha = .2) +
  scale_color_viridis_d(name = "poly_sf") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("pre-idw")

# inverse distance weighted interpolation of points on polygon lines,
# play around with idp (inverse distance weighting power) values, 2 is default
idw_stars <- idw(value ~ 1, points_sf, grd, idp = 2)
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]

# sf countour lines from raster
contour_sf <- idw_stars |> 
  st_contour(contour_lines = TRUE, breaks = 11:19)
names(contour_sf)[1] <- "value"

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_stars(data = idw_stars) +
  geom_sf(data = contour_sf, aes(color = "countours")) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "transparent") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(countours = "grey20"), name = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("post-idw")

patchwork::wrap_plots(p1,p2)
```

[image]

```r
# combine interpolated contour(s) with input sf
out_sf <- contour_sf[contour_sf$value == 13, ] |> 
  st_polygonize() |> 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON") |> 
  rbind(poly_sf)
```

Resulting `sf` object:

```r
out_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 20 ymin: -3 xmax: 25 ymax: 5
#> CRS:           NA
#>    value                       geometry
#> 25    13 POLYGON ((22.975 0.8220076,...
#> 1     10 POLYGON ((21 1, 22 2, 23 1,...
#> 2     20 POLYGON ((21 0, 20 3, 22 5,...

# reorder for plot
out_sf$value <- as.factor(out_sf$value)
out_sf <- out_sf[rev(rank(st_area(out_sf))),] 
plot(out_sf)
```

[image]

##### Edit: other interpolation methods

*IDW* is just one of many interpolations methods; there's a good chance that some others are either faster and/or deliver more suitable results so it would probably be a good idea to look into Kriging methods (same `gstat` package) and maybe few others. E.g. one super-simple approach would be k-Nearest Neighbour Classification to detect the distance boundary between 2 different point classes:

```r
knn_stars <- grd
knn_class <- class::knn(st_coordinates(points_sf), st_coordinates(grd), points_sf$value, k = 1)
knn_stars$values <- as.numeric(levels(knn_class))[knn_class]

contour_knn_sf <- knn_stars |> 
  st_contour(contour_lines = TRUE)
names(contour_knn_sf)[1] <- "value"

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = poly_sf, fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = contour_sf, aes(color = as.factor(value)), linewidth = 1.5, alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf(data = contour_knn_sf, aes(color = "cont. knn"), linewidth = 1.5) + 
  scale_color_viridis_d(name = "contrours")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I have  provisonally chosen this answer because it provides more relaistic spatial data than a direct buffering as suggestd below. however with large rasters, this could become slow. I had hoped to avoid rasterizing. Thanks a lot. There is still some promise in the method  proposed by @SamR if the susbjectivity introduced by a fixed outer_buffer can be removed and if segmentizing can be added

Comment: I have made further comments to the solution by @samR after testing  and conclude that for now this IDW interpolation is the best solution.

Comment: idw, as presented here, is probably one of the most basic interpolation approaches, so I'd recommend you look into other methods as well. I added knn as an additional example , simple, but not so smooth, yet it might work quite nicely with actual contour lines.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, this is a lot like buffering. It seems to me that we can approach it as creating a buffer around the inner polygon of whatever size your `value` is, and clipping that buffer to ensure it is never outside the outer polygon.

I've defined a function to do this, `interpolate_polygon()`. It first uses `st_buffer()` and then `st_intersection()` with the outer polygon for the clipping. You can plot the polygons created for selected values like this (original polygons red and blue, interpolated polygon is green):

```r
vals_to_interpolate <- c(11, 13, 15, 17)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (val in vals_to_interpolate) {
    plot(pol2, border = "blue", main = sprintf("value: %s", val), cex.main = 3, lwd = 3)
    plot(pol1, border = "red", , lwd = 3, add = T)
    plot(interpolate_polygon(pol2, pol1, val),
        border = "green", , lwd = 3, add = T
    )
}
```

[image]

#### Function definition

Here is the definition of `interpolate_polygon()`.

```r
interpolate_polygon <- function(
    p_outer, p_inner, scale_val = 15,
    p_inner_val = 10, p_outer_val = 20,
    outer_buffer = 0.95) {
    # Just return outer polygon if you scale
    # all the way up

    if (scale_val == p_outer_val) {
        return(p_outer)
    }

    # Create a polygon that the inner polygon
    # can never extend past
    p_outer_scaled <- p_outer * outer_buffer
    p_outer_scaled <- p_outer_scaled - st_centroid(p_outer_scaled) + st_centroid(p_outer)

    p_inner_range <- as.matrix(p_inner) |>
        apply(2, range)

    p_outer_range <- as.matrix(p_outer) |>
        apply(2, range)

    max_stretch <- max(abs(p_outer_range - p_inner_range))

    # Create a buffer of appropriate size
    # cubic scaling seems to work
    buffer_val <- scales::rescale(
        scale_val^3,
        c(0, max_stretch),
        c(p_inner_val^3, p_outer_val^3)
    )

    p_scaled <- st_intersection(
        st_buffer(p_inner, buffer_val, joinStyle = "MITRE"),
        p_outer_scaled
    )

    p_scaled
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but introduces some subjectivity on the outer boundary of the result due to a constat outer_buffer. You provide a good rough estimate. The the answer from @margusl works better for my kind of data although it provides some challenges with respect to speed if the raster is large. Thanks a lot. I have learnt alot from your approach and have a couple of ways i will use this.  I feel through that your solution  could work well if the outer_buffer  is not set at a constant 0.95 but varied based on the <scale_value> and also if segmentizing can be added before buffering.

Comment: on second thought (after trial and error) i see that this solution creates a constat  buffer based on scaling the values  and then  clipping. I am now of the view that this requirs substanstial modification in order to attain the result needed.

Comment: @jjunju are you referring to the buffer created in `p_outer_scaled` or the one created in `p_scaled`? The former is constant but that shouldn't matter - it's to stop the inner polygon extending outside the outer polygon. You could get rid of it if you want or just make it `p_outer`. The latter is not constant - you might want to play around with the scaling though. I made it cubic because it worked in your example, where there's a lot of space for the shape to extend on the y-axis but not much on the x-axis. I don't know what your real data looks like, but yes it may require some modification.

Comment: even for p_scaled the buffer is a constant valuye around the entire polygon. i.e buffer_val though varies with scale_val but still leads to a constat buffer around the polygon. That is what i meant by constant buffer distance. it doesnt vary by node or line segment.